# unable to use com.google.android.maps in the xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, maps

I am designing an app that uses google maps. In order to get maps I have used the following code:

```
    com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0V1xMgGND8LqWx0wO3Vkgs8Rj27aVCRp0biowfw" />
```

In the xml file but the app force closes after running it.

If I don't use this part then the rest of the code executes all fine.

1. used google APIs 2.3 as target
2. sdk version 1.6
3. using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 
   Version: Indigo Service Release 2
   Build id: 20120216-1857
4. i have put  within the
   application tag in the manifest file.
5. I have even used the permissions

*I can however compile it without any errors but unable to run it.
I cant really figure it out.
this is the log generated by the logcat.
can i get some help from anyone...?*

```
   04-29 22:14:32.553: D/dalvikvm(415): GC_CONCURRENT freed 261K, 48% free
    2963K/5639K, external 411K/517K, paused 5ms+5ms
   04-29 22:14:32.863: D/dalvikvm(415): GC_CONCURRENT freed 447K, 49% free
    3086K/5959K, external 411K/517K, paused 5ms+7ms
   04-29 22:14:33.133: D/dalvikvm(415): GC_CONCURRENT freed 326K, 46% free
    3271K/6023K, external 411K/517K, paused 5ms+6ms
   04-29 22:14:33.203: D/AndroidRuntime(415): Shutting down VM
   04-29 22:14:33.203: W/dalvikvm(415): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught
    exception (group=0x40015560)
   04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
    start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.map/com.my.map.MapActivity}:
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class
    com.google.android.maps.MapView
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
     (ZygoteInit.java:839)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
       Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415):    
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView
       (PhoneWindow.java:207)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at com.my.map.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:17)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415):    
         ... 11 more
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): Caused by:
       java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415):    ... 21 more
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): Caused by:
      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created insideinstances
         ofMapActivity.
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:291)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:264)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415): 
  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:247)
  04-29 22:14:33.303: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  
    ... 24 more
 04-29 22:14:45.193: I/Process(415): Sending signal. PID: 415 SIG: 9**
```

Comment: try including the maps library in the project.. you can get that from your android-sdk -> addons

Answer (score 0):

Try not using the "wrap_content" for height as it seems to throw and inflation exception. Try going for a dp value. Or if you want to have it adjust to some specific place in the layout, use a relative layout and have it stretch relative to other view elements. Just don't use "wrap_content" by itself.

If that did not work, get back to me and I will try to assist further.

Comment: Hello OneManMobile, i have changed the fields where "wrap content" is used. I have specified my own values in dp. I can see the graphical layout but the app still force closes. . I have followed this tutorial joshclemm.com/blog/?p=148

Answer (score 0):

below the application tag add `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` inside
the xml specify `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

If possible try to change project build target `Project->Properties->Android`to Google APIs level.